Multi-Agent Navigation using online RRT Algorithm
I have code that deals with multi-agent navigation in an environment with static and dynamic obstacles. I use multi-process (in VS Python). The agents receive random tasks for navigation (start point and end point) and as soon as an agent finishes its task, it immediately receives a new task. I have a problem with the amount of tasks that each agent runs. I get a very large gap between the amount of tasks that a certain agent does compared to the rest (it could be 950 tasks compared to 10-20 tasks, etc.) I think that there may be a problem with the corresponding code of the program for running the RRT (I think there is no bug in the code itself because when I ran it on an existing DATA SET of routes, I got relatively identical results for each agent). I am attaching here part of the code that deals with concurrency and also the output I received that shows the gap between the results.
This is the main function :
def agent_worker(agent_id, agent_states, shared_stats, shared_env, stop_signal):
    """
    Worker function for each agent.
    """
    from agent_navigation import agent_run_simulation
    agent_run_simulation(agent_id, agent_states, shared_stats, shared_env, stop_signal)

def main(routes, up_inflated_matrix, original_scaled_matrix, original_black_ranges, time_limit_minutes, num_agents):
    """
    Main function to manage agents and coordinate the simulation.
    """
    # Convert time limit to seconds
    time_limit = time_limit_minutes * 60
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    stop_signal = multiprocessing.Event()  # Signal to stop agents

    # Shared statistics
    shared_stats = manager.dict({
        'COUNT_ALL_COLL': 0,
        'COUNT_ALL_FAILED': 0,
        'COUNT_ALL_ROUTES': 0,
        'TOTAL_TASKS_COMPLETED': 0,
    })

    # Shared environment
    shared_env = manager.dict({
        'original_scaled_matrix': original_scaled_matrix.tolist() if isinstance(original_scaled_matrix, np.ndarray) else original_scaled_matrix,
        'up_inflated_matrix': up_inflated_matrix.tolist() if isinstance(up_inflated_matrix, np.ndarray) else up_inflated_matrix,
        'original_black_ranges': original_black_ranges,
        'routes': routes,
    })

    # Shared agent states
    agent_states = manager.dict({
        i: {
            "current_position": None,
            "tasks": [],
            "completed_tasks": 0,
            "collisions": 0,
            "failed_tasks": 0,
        }
        for i in range(num_agents)
    })

    # Generate start and end points for initial tasks
    start_points, end_points = generate_start_and_end(up_inflated_matrix, original_black_ranges, num_agents=num_agents, min_distance=4)

    for agent_id in range(num_agents):
        # Fetch the current agent state
        agent_state = agent_states[agent_id]  # Retrieve the dictionary for this agent

        # Update the agent's state
        agent_state["current_position"] = start_points[agent_id]
        agent_state["tasks"] = [{"start_point": start_points[agent_id], "end_point": end_points[agent_id]}]

        # Reassign the modified state back to agent_states
        agent_states[agent_id] = agent_state

        # Debug print
        print(f"**** Agent {agent_id} initial position: {agent_states[agent_id]['current_position']}")

    # Create and start processes for agents
    processes = []
    for agent_id in range(num_agents):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=agent_worker,
            args=(agent_id, agent_states, shared_stats, shared_env, stop_signal)
        )
        processes.append(process)
        process.start()

    # Monitor the simulation time
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < time_limit:
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Allow agents to work

    # Stop all agents
    stop_signal.set()

    # Wait for all processes to complete
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    # Print global statistics
    keys_to_print = ['COUNT_ALL_COLL', 'COUNT_ALL_FAILED', 'COUNT_ALL_ROUTES', 'TOTAL_TASKS_COMPLETED']
    filtered_stats = {key: shared_stats[key] for key in keys_to_print}
    print(f"Global Statistics: {filtered_stats}")

i try to use multiprocess and follow after the results and this is what i got :
7 agents:
%%% Agent 3: mission:960 , failed:0, in total: mission: 1324  failed: 8
%%% Agent 1: mission:1 , failed:1, in total: mission: 1325  failed: 9
%%% Agent 0: mission:5 , failed:0, in total: mission: 1325  failed: 9
%%% Agent 5: mission:18 , failed:0, in total: mission: 1325  failed: 9
%%% Agent 6: mission:20 , failed:1, in total: mission: 1326  failed: 10
%%% Agent 2: mission:108 , failed:1, in total: mission: 1327  failed: 11
%%% Agent 4: mission:217 , failed:0, in total: mission: 1327  failed: 11
Global Statistics: {'COUNT_ALL_COLL': 144, 'COUNT_ALL_FAILED': 11, 'COUNT_ALL_ROUTES': 1359, 'TOTAL_TASKS_COMPLETED': 1327}
as i mentioned above , certain agent does a lot of tasks( 960 missions ) compared to the rest and there is no relatively equal division of the tasks.
I would appreciate for help on how to deal with this problem since it is incorrect results, because if one agent does a lot of tasks and the rest do few tasks, it means that there is really no parallelism in the program and an agent takes over the execution while the rest stand aside and don't move.
Thank you very much everyone, I appreciate your help.
